# Program started with Task Scheduler could not open my Printer

Tags: c#, printing, service, windows-task-scheduler

I have a C# program that executes some commands that generates a pdf and print it to a printer. The printer is hosted in a print server, so the way I accessed the printer is through my app config. (\Print Server Name\Printer Name)

```
<add key="printServerPrinter" value="\\APPS-UATSVR\NPIFBCC54 (HP LaserJet MFP M430)"/>
```

This program works when I run it on visual studio or even when I release it and run it via its .exe file. It has to run during work hours so I added it to Task Scheduler to start it to check something every minute and print when it found something.

The problem is if the program is started by the Task Scheduler It couldn't find the printer, it generates a pdf but can't send it to print on the printer since it couldnt find/open it. This is the error  logged on a .txt file.

```
2023-07-26 06:32:43:751191 Function:Main - Message:The printer named "\\APPS-UATSVR\NPIFBCC54 (HP LaserJet MFP M430)" could not be opened. Error code: 0
```

If I start it normally there are no problems, as I have said earlier. I searched around the net but couldn't find an answer and i can't seem to debug this problem. I've tried many ways, changed the printer name, changed the port, change the backslash to forward slash but it still wont work.

What seems to be the problem? Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at which user the task is running as? It may need to run as your user account or as an administrator instead of the system account to access the printer. Check the Task Properties and the user is here:

[image]

Comment: It still doesnt work. I've changed the user when running to task to web_admin. And It still doesnt changed anything :(

Comment: @Kraust123 \\ is a network location so it might need to run as your own user account

Comment: what own user account? web_admin is the user accouunt running the task scheduler

Comment: I forgot to mention that the task scheduler is running on different server –

Comment: Is this an Active Directory environment? You'll likely need to create a service account for the Task to run as and that account will need permissions on the printer.